# How would you find number of solutions without solving this$N=\overline{x52yzt}=11k$, such that $x+5+2+y+z+t=11m$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

How would you find number of solutions without solving this problem:

Find N with following condition:

$N=\overline{x52yzt}=11k$, such that $x+5+2+y+z+t=11m$?

I saw this problem in a book and it gives 8 solutions, but I found 56 solutions by computer which includes all solutions in the book. The method used in the book needed to solve numerous system of Diophantine equations. I have two questions:

1-How would you find number of solutions without solving it.

2- Is there a simpler method to solve this kind of problems without computer?

Solutions by computer:

(x, 5, 2, y, z, t)=(1, 5, 2, 0, 8, 6) (1, 5, 2, 1, 8, 5) (1, 5, 2, 2, 8, 4) (1, 5, 2, 3, 8, 3) (1, 5, 2, 4, 8, 2) (1, 5, 2, 5, 8, 1) (1, 5, 2, 6, 8, 0) (2, 5, 2, 0, 7, 6) (2, 5, 2, 1, 7, 5) (2, 5, 2, 2, 7, 4) (2, 5, 2, 3, 7, 3) (2, 5, 2, 4, 7, 2) (2, 5, 2, 5, 7, 1) (2, 5, 2, 6, 7, 0) (3, 5, 2, 0, 6, 6) (3, 5, 2, 1, 6, 5) (3, 5, 2, 2, 6, 4) (3, 5, 2, 3, 6, 3) (3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 2) (3, 5, 2, 5, 6, 1) (3, 5, 2, 6, 6, 0) (4, 5, 2, 0, 5, 6) (4, 5, 2, 1, 5, 5) (4, 5, 2, 2, 5, 4) (4, 5, 2, 3, 5, 3) (4, 5, 2, 4, 5, 2) (4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 1) (4, 5, 2, 6, 5, 0) (5, 5, 2, 0, 4, 6) (5, 5, 2, 1, 4, 5) (5, 5, 2, 2, 4, 4) (5, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3) (5, 5, 2, 4, 4, 2) (5, 5, 2, 5, 4, 1) (5, 5, 2, 6, 4, 0) (6, 5, 2, 0, 3, 6) (6, 5, 2, 1, 3, 5) (6, 5, 2, 2, 3, 4) (6, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3) (6, 5, 2, 4, 3, 2) (6, 5, 2, 5, 3, 1) (6, 5, 2, 6, 3, 0) (7, 5, 2, 0, 2, 6) (7, 5, 2, 1, 2, 5) (7, 5, 2, 2, 2, 4) (7, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3) (7, 5, 2, 4, 2, 2) (7, 5, 2, 5, 2, 1) (7, 5, 2, 6, 2, 0) (8, 5, 2, 0, 1, 6) (8, 5, 2, 1, 1, 5) (8, 5, 2, 2, 1, 4) (8, 5, 2, 3, 1, 3) (8, 5, 2, 4, 1, 2) (8, 5, 2, 5, 1, 1) (8, 5, 2, 6, 1, 0)

Solutions found in book:

$152086, 152680, 852016, 352869, 352968, 652839, 652938$

Answer (score 1):

Note that the solution $(x,5,2,y,t)=(1,5,2,9,8,8)$ is not found by your computer.

By the divisibility tests for $\overline{x52yzt}$, we conclude that $(x+2+z)-5+y+t)=11a$

Since we already have $(x+2+z)+(5+y+t)=11m$, then we get

$$\Big((x+2+z)-(5+y+t)\Big) \pm \Big((x+2+z)+(5+y+t)\Big)=11(a \pm m)$$

Thus both $x+2+z$ and $5+y+t$ are divisible by $11$

Thus all we need to do is to determine the number of solutions to the following equations

> $$x+z=9$$ or $$x+z=20$$

and

> $$y+t=6 $$ or $$y+t=17$$

Since $x \ne 0$ then $(x,z)$ has $9$ possibilites, while $(y,t)$ has $9$ possibilites. That gives you a total of $81$ solutions.

Comment: There are in fact only $81$, and I believe you know where the mistake was made.

Comment: Not $0{}{{}{{}}}$

Comment: Can a six digit number start with zero?

Comment: @player3236, Corrected

Comment: @SunShine, Could you please add your computer program and its results to your answer, I want to check 81 solutions.

Comment: I have not used any computer program, Hence I cannot add the code. As I said $(1,5,2,9,8,8)$ is a solution that your computer has missed.